# Autofac generic registration

Tags: c#, autofac

Is there a way I can accomplish something like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<DbContext>().Set<TEntity>()).As(IDbSet<TEntity>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and there's even a pattern for that. It's called the repository pattern:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(Guid id);
}

public class EntityFrameworkRepository<TEntity> : IEntity<TEntity>
{
    private readonly DbContext context;

    public EntityFrameworkRepository(DbContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll() {
        return this.context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(Guid id) {
        var item = this.context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);

        if (item == null) throw new KeyNotFoundException(id.ToString());

        return item;
    }
}
```

You can register it as follows:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

Comment: Is IEntity supposed to be IRepository?